# Django Middleware object is not callable

Tags: django, python-3.6, middleware, django-middleware

I'm trying to write custom middleware for catching exceptions and returning the proper HTTP Response object. But for some reason, I'm getting a "middleware object is not callable" error.

I'm raising an exception in view layer like below

```
class MyView(APIView):
  def post(self, request):
    result = some_func(request) #this func raises an exception
    return Response({"status": "Success", "data": result})
```

logs.

```
backend_1          | INFO:django:BEGIN -> c25db666-e89c-43a5-9f28-48001e301829 - /myapp/settings/create
backend_1          | {"message": "Internal Server Error: /myapp/settings/create", "exc_info": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py\", line 47, in inner\n    response = get_response(request)\nTypeError: 'MyAppResponseMiddleware' object is not callable", "status_code": 500, "request": "<WSGIRequest: POST '/myapp/settings/create'>"}
backend_1          | ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /crystal/settings/create
backend_1          | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend_1          |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
backend_1          |     response = get_response(request)
backend_1          | TypeError: 'MyAppResponseMiddleware' object is not callable
```

files

```
#myapp/middleware.py
class MyAppResponseMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        absolute_path = request.get_full_path()
        print(absolute_path)
        print(exception.__class__.name)
        print(exception.message)
    
#settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    ...
    ...
    <some custom middleware>
    ...
    "myapp.middleware.MyAppResponseMiddleware",
        ]
```

I've added middleware in the last so that my middleware catches the response/exception before other middleware process the response.

[debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu2Ub.png)
I guess when the call reaches the middleware, it itself is an HTTPresponse object instead of an exception. I'm not sure, why it is not reaching process_exception

Comment: versions:

djangorestframework==3.11.2,
python 3.9.7

Answer (score 0):

According to docs Middleware should be a callable (function or class with __call__ method) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Structure should be like:

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added the `__call__` method. Now the error is gone. But I couldn't catch any exception in the process_exception method. In `__call__` method at `return response` line it returns the response to the next middleware. process_exception func is not even catching anythin

Comment: I've added a debug screenshot in the question, pls take a look

Comment: Maybe no exception is raised?

Comment: No, Exception is raising.